# How to check if a parameter is passed to a function?

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a dataframe is passed or not as a parameter

```py
def mean_encoding_with_reg (df,var,alpha,y,test=False): 

    if test!=False:
        test.set_index(var,inplace=True)
        test['cat_'+str(var)] = a.mean_y
        test.reset_index(inplace=True)
        test.drop(var,inplace=True,axis=1)

    return df,test
```

In case I pass a test param I get the following message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code merely defines a function and quits.  You failed to provide the entire error message (include the trace-back).

Comment: Don't you want `def ...(..., test = None)` and then `if test:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use isinstance() to check whether the "test" argument is a dataframe.

```
if isinstance(test, pandas.DataFrame):
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Spinor8 for your help. Here's how I implemented it:

def mean_encoding_with_reg (df,var,alpha,y,test=False):

```
if isinstance(test, pd.DataFrame):
    test.set_index(var,inplace=True)
    test['cat_'+str(var)] = a.mean_y
    test.reset_index(inplace=True)
    test.drop(var,inplace=True,axis=1)
    return df,test 
return df
```